# Strange behaviour in nested For Loops

Tags: c++

First of all, I'm pretty new to C++ so try not to be too harsh on me. I wrote this block of code:

```
int LargestProduct (string numStr, int groupSize) {
    int numOfGroups = numStr.size() / groupSize;
    int groupsRemaining = numStr.size() % groupSize;

    int largestProduct = 0, thisProduct = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfGroups; i++) {

        for (int j = i; j <= groupSize; j++)
            thisProduct *= (numStr[j-1] - '0');

        if (thisProduct > largestProduct)
            largestProduct = thisProduct;

        thisProduct = 1;
    }

    // .. A bit more irrelevant code here

    return largestProduct;
}
```

The function call `LargestProduct ("1234567890", 2)` should yield `72`, but it wrongly yields `6`. So, for some reason, this code will work **but not as expected** (Note: this code I wrote should compute the largest product of `groupsSize`-adjacent numbers in a big, given number called `numStr`).

I did some debugging, and found a strange behaviour in the nested for-loop. I set up a breakpoint inside the second for-loop

`thisProduct *= (numStr[j] - '0');`

After some iterations (for example, 8 iterations), this is **what I would expect** i and j to be:

```
+--------+---------+
|   i    |    j    |
+--------+---------+
|    1   |    1    |
|    1   |    2    |
|    2   |    1    |
|    2   |    2    |
|    3   |    1    |
|    3   |    2    |
|    4   |    1    |
|    4   |    2    |
+--------+---------+
```

This is **what really happens**:

```
+--------+---------+
|   i    |    j    |
+--------+---------+
|    1   |    1    |
|    1   |    2    |
|    2   |    2    |
+--------+---------+
```

And suddenly the program spits out a wrong result (`6`, instead of `72`)

But this seems counterintuitive, to say the least. The variable `i` goes from `0` to `numOfGroups`, which in the example above equals `5`. On the other hand, `j` goes from `i` to `groupSize`, which happens to be `2`.

There should be `5*2 = 10` iterations, but there are only `3` of them. Also, in the last iteration, j should be "re-initialized" to `0`. This doesn't happen though.

[image: debugger-screenshot]

Anyone please help this C++ newbie?

---

**EDIT**
The problem was that the j-for-loop ranged from a moving index (`i`) to a non-moving index(`groupSize`). This was causing that "shrinking" effect in the second for-loop, which is easily fixed by changing this line:

```
for (int j = i; j <= groupSize; j++)
```

To this other one:

```
for (int j = i; j <= i + groupSize - 1; j++)
```

And to make the full algorithm to work as expected, one should also replace these lines:

```
int numOfGroups = numStr.size() / groupSize;
int groupsRemaining = numStr.size() % groupSize;
```

with this single one:

```
int numOfGroups = numStr.size() - 1;
```

---

**EDIT 2**
Everything is OK now, thank you for your kindness guys! I appreciate it. The whole code is:

```
int LargestProduct (string numStr, int groupSize) {
    int numOfGroups = numStr.size() - 1;
    int largestProduct = 0, thisProduct = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfGroups; i++) {

        for (int j = i; j <= i + groupSize - 1; j++)
            thisProduct *= (numStr[j-1] - '0');

        if (thisProduct > largestProduct)
            largestProduct = thisProduct;

        thisProduct = 1;
    }
    return largestProduct;
}
```

Comment: Array indexes start at 0.

Comment: Thanks @manni66, I knew that but made the mistake. However this doesn't solve the issue. Now the program yields `2` instead of `6` but that's all.

Comment: *"in the last iteration, `j` should be "re-initialized" to 0"* - why should it? What part of your code tells it to?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: do you mean to have `for (int j = 1; j <= groupSize; j++)`, after which you should consider that arrays start with 0 and end with size()-1.

Comment: Thank you guys. Any advices to not getting this many downvotes next time? I tried to present the problem as clearly as I could, showing some effort and background effort on my part. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to find the largest product in the pairs of {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} etc, or something else? If you do it that way then something like this is what you want, and the answer is 56 (7*8): https://ideone.com/4vv227 It's really not clear what algorithm you're trying to apply, especially since your math isn't correct for indices.

Comment: But you are taking the number in pairs: {1,2}; {2,3}; {3,4} ... {8,9}, {9,0}. The biggest number is 8*9=72. Thanks for your insights, I fixed the index problem

Comment: If you are sliding the groupsize window one index at a time then you have more than 5 groups which makes more of your code invalid. If that is the case you have 9 groups and your code would look something like this: https://ideone.com/3pNqKy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

*On the other hand, j goes from 0 to groupSize*

But the code says:

```
for (int j = i; j <= groupSize; j++)
```

This means j is going from i to `groupSize`, not 0 to `groupSize`

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia Are you really sure the words are wrong and not the code? It's a contradiction to your expectation of `j` toggling between 1 and 2.

Comment: @nwp and Steve You are both right. My words were right, the code was wrong! I will delete, this question since it seems to have been very badly laid out, it got 4 downvotes already. Some advices to not get many downvotes next time? I tried to lay out the problem as clearly I could, showing some concern and effort behind it. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the answer, if you feel it answers your question :) As for the downvotes, I couldn't say - there didn't seem to be much wrong with it to my eyes but I'm not particularly experienced here myself.

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia imho one problem with the question is that both the code and your expectations are wrong. In general it helps to provide code that is ready to be compiled and run by others (you are missing a main). And dont worry about the downvotes too much. You care about solving the problem, not about the rep, right?

Comment: Yes @tobi303, but two or three more of these and I'll be forbidden to ask for life. This is sad, but I'll do much better next time.